# ValueError: time data '02/03/2022' does not match format '%d/%m/%y '

Tags: python, datetime, valueerror

[How to return values only within a specific date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067054/how-to-return-values-only-within-a-specific-date-range)

I am new to python

My code is:

```
for report_date in REPORT_DATE_TYPES:
    if report_date in result:
        date = result[report_date].split(' ')[0]
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y ')
```

but I am getting an error:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '02/03/2022' does not match format '%d/%m/%y '
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `%y` is a 2-digit year, `%Y` is 4-digit year. Also, you have a space in the format string, does `date` end with a space?

Comment: 4-digit year is `%Y` not `%y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To point out the year you need to use `%Y` and also there is an additional space at the end of the format you gave that it's not present in the date. Try with `date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Thank you that worked, Can I use : if date < last_date to run operations only if the date is lesser than the last_date.

Comment: I had posted a question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067054/how-to-return-values-only-within-a-specific-date-range. I have been stuck on this for over a day.

Comment: Once you convert them to datatime you can compare them with classic comparison operators. I will also have a look at the other question you posted

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You can refresh the page as I have changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `%y` refers to just the last 2 digit of the year, not the whole year as you have in the example.

`20/03/21` is in format `'%d/%m/%y` while
`20/03/2021` is in format `'%d/%m/%Y`(note the capital `Y`) therefore you just need to update the code as following

```
for report_date in REPORT_DATE_TYPES:
   if report_date in result:
       date = result[report_date].split(' ')[0]
       date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y ')
```

You can find an useful table of each flag [on this link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime)

Answer (score -1):

This error indicates that format and input are not aligned.
In this example the input: '02/03/2022',
does not match format '%d/%m/%y'

Why?
Since %y is a year with two letter, such as '22' rather than '2022'.
BTW, the rest of the input does match the format.

Use this link to verify the format in correct:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).